# sort a list from the word that appears the most to the word that appear the less

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, list

given a string and I need to sort from the word that appears the most to the word that appears the less and each word will appear once in a list.

```py
s = "hi, you , you, hi, they, no, no, no"
```

The result will be:

```py
list = ['no','hi','you','they']
```

Do you have any advice how to change my code so that it will work?
without any collection functions

```
s="hello, word, word, love, love, love, hi, you"
counter=0
i=0
l=[]
ln=[]
max=1
s=s.split(',')
print(s)

for word in s:
   for i in range(len(s)-1):
     current_max=s.count(word)
     if current_max>max:
        max=current_max
        temp=s[i]
        s[i]=word
        s[i+1]=s[i]
        i=+1

for word in s:
   if word in ln:
         continue
   else:
         ln.append(word)
```

print(ln)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `collections.Counter` with `set`:

```
import collections
s="hi, you, you, hi, they, no, no, no"
d = collections.Counter(s.split(', '))
result = sorted(set(s.split(', ')), key=lambda x:d[x], reverse=True)
```

Output:

```
['no', 'hi', 'you', 'they']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can utilize `Counter.most_common()` method:

```
s="hi, you , you, hi, they, no, no, no"

from collections import Counter

print([w for w, _ in Counter(map(str.strip, s.split(','))).most_common()])
```

Prints:

```
['no', 'hi', 'you', 'they']
```

---

EDIT: Regarding your code, you can make `counter` dict with keys as words from your string and values as number of how many the word appeared in string. Then sort the dictionary based on values:

```
s="hi, you , you, hi, they, no, no, no"

s=s.split(',')

counter = {}
for word in s:
    w = word.strip()
    if w not in counter:
        counter[w] = 1
    else:
        counter[w] += 1

print([i for i, _ in sorted(counter.items(), key=lambda k: -k[1])])
```

Prints:

```
['no', 'hi', 'you', 'they']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sorted` function with `key` parameter.

```
get_count = lambda word: s.count(word)
new_s = sorted(s, key=get_count, reversed=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by Enzo, with little modification:

```py
s="hello, word, word, love, love, love, hi, you"
s=s.split(', ')
ordered_words = sorted(set(s), reverse=True, key=s.count)
print(ordered_words)
```

Regarding your code:
you need to use `s.split(', ')` instead of `s.split(',')`, because if the first word is used several times, it will be seen as 2 different words.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Counter` to find the count of each word and then its `most_common` method to sort them based on occurrence

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> s = "hi, you, you, hi, they, no, no, no"
>>> [w for w,_ in Counter(s.split(', ')).most_common()]
['no', 'hi', 'you', 'they']
```

Answer (score 0):

Please find the below algorithm and code for your question.

```
'''
1. split the words in a string to form list
2. Count number of words repeated in a list
3. Store the "count": "word" as a dictionary
'''

s = s.split(",")
print(s)

def unique(list):
    unique_words=[]
    for i in list:
      if i not in unique_words:
        unique_words.append(i)

    return unique_words

u=(unique(s))


def count(word,list):
    count =0
    for i in list:
        if i == word:
            count +=1
    return count

dict = {}
list =[]
for i in u:
    x = count(i,s)
    if x in dict:
        list.append(dict[x])
        list.append(i)
        dict[x] = list
    else:
        dict[x] = i

print(dict)

key =[]
for k in dict:
    key.append(k)

final_list =[]
for i in key:
    v = dict.get(i)
    if type(v) ==list:
        for u in v:
            if type(u) == str:
                final_list.append(u)
    else:
        final_list.append(v)
print(final_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple solution:

```py
s = "hi, you, you, hi, they, no, no, no".split(', ')

list = []
for item in s:
    if item not in list:
        list.append(item)
print(list)
```

or you can do a list comprehension:

```
s = "hi, you, you, hi, they, no, no, no".split(', ')

list = []
[list.append(item) for item in s if item not in list]
print(list)
```